# Select all rows with distinct column value using LINQ

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have a database with 4 fields that looks something like this:

```
ID      DeviceId       Location        Date
1           A             ...            2
2           A             ...            1
3           B             ...            2
```

For each `DeviceId` I want the location from the record with the highest date. I can get the distinct `DeviceId`'s like this:

```
// get all locations
var locations = Session.Query<Location>().ToList();

//Get the latest used unique deviceId's
var distinctDeviceIdsByDate = (
      from loc in locations
      orderby loc.DeviceId, loc.Date descending
      select loc.DeviceId).Distinct().ToList();
```

I would then use join to get the wanted rows, but this won't do any good since I can't get anything other than the `DeviceId`'s and therefore can't identify which rows to select. and if I try to select the following:

```
select loc
```

I can only get the rows with unique combinations of all the columns. I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I'm afraid I can't figure it out right now.

Comment: So for each device ID you want the location from the record with the highest date?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'll edit the question to say what you said.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question to include the answer; you should mark the one you think is correct or help you the most.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have to use some combination of `GroupBy` and `Take`. Try this,

```
var distinctDeviceIdsByDate = 
    locations.OrderByDescending(location => location.DeviceId)
             .ThenByDescending(location => location.Date)
             .GroupBy(location => location.DeviceId)
             .SelectMany(location => location.Take(1));
```

Comment: Looks like this works the way I want! I will update the question with your solution, accredited to you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Date` is unique per `DeviceId` you could try

```
//Get the latest used unique deviceId's
var distinctDeviceIdsByDate = (
      from loc in Session.Query<Location>()
      group loc by loc.DeviceId
      into g
      select new
      {
          DeviceID = g.Key,  
          Location = g.OrderByDescending(l => l.Date).First().Location;
      };
```

Comment: This looks like a possible solution aswell, but since the answer from DotNetWala worked I will use it for now and investigate other solutions should I encounter problems down the road.

Comment: This will not work with NHibernate and will throw the following SqlException: Column 'Location.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grouping to solve this.

```
var locations = new [] {
    new { DeviceId = "A", Date = 2, Location = ".." },
    new { DeviceId = "A", Date = 1, Location = ".." },
    new { DeviceId = "B", Date = 2, Location = "...." },
};

var lastUsedLocations = 
    from l in locations
    group l by l.DeviceId into g
    let lastUsed = g.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Last()
    select lastUsed;

// lastUsedLocations contains
// DeviceId       Date        Location
// A              2           ..
// B              2           ....
```

Comment: This looks like a possible solution aswell, but since the answer from DotNetWala worked I will use it for now and investigate other solutions should I encounter problems down the road.

Comment: They are essentially the same. The key concept is grouping.